# ProviderNotFoundException | widget test for a button, can not successfully test the button text

Tags: flutter, testing, button, widget-test-flutter

I am writing a widget test for a button widget, but the text part can not be tested successfully.

Here is the widget testing code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:ui_widgets/src/modules/buttons/elevated_button.dart';

void main() {

  testWidgets('Button testing', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      const Material(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          buttonText: 'button text',
        ),
      ),
    );

    await tester.pump();

    expect(find.text('button text'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Here is the Error log:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building ElevatedButton(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppTheme> above this ElevatedButton Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that ElevatedButton is under your MultiProvider/Provider<AppTheme>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
```

**Q1:**
**How to deal with this exception?**

**Q2:**
**ow to test on other widget function of the button (i.e. onPress function)?**

(Expect a bug-free code can pass the test. Thanks!)